# Sticky-Kit doesnt work on first scroll

Tags: jquery, sticky

Hi I am using http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/ plugin to stick my navbar to the top of the window when it reaches the top. It works but weirdly not on the first instance. Once I scroll back up and down again it works perfect.There is alot of code and the sticky kit code is basically telling the plugin which element to stick to his parent so I havent included any here. Has anybody else encountered this problem.
I have a test domain at www.test.mrjinxy.com. I would appreciate any help.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell which element you are calling the stick_in_parent() function on, but I had the same issue with the "sticky" element disappearing on the first scroll but then working after scrolling back up.

My issue ended up being that I needed to clearfix my parent div. The parent div had no height because it only contained floated elements. After using a clearfix on the parent div the scrolling issue went away. I used the method from this article: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Here is an example of what I had to do:

Old code:

```
<style>
  #sticky {
    float: left;
  }    
</style>

<div id="container">
  <div id="sticky">
  </div>
</div>
```

Revised code:

```
<style>
  #container {
    /* Clearfix */
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #sticky {
    float: left;
  }    
</style>

<div id="container">
  <div id="sticky">
  </div>
</div>
```